# How to count downloads from Google Play

Tags: download, statistics, google-play, report, store

i published my first app on Google Play and i can't figure out how to count the total of downloads by users.
It lets me to choose between currents installations and uninstallations per day, but none that tells me the total of downloads since the publishing of the app.
To count the total of downloads i take the number of installations and i substract the total of uninstallations (i get it making the sum of uninstallations of every day!)

How to figure out the total of downloads in an easier way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Google Developer Console and nothing programming related

Comment: How to change the topic?

Comment: make it a question about programming

Comment: I edited my questions. Does it do the job?

Comment: why do u need that? isnt the analytic console in your developer account informative enough for you?

Comment: I would know how many times my app has been downloaded and the developer console doesn't show it. Am i wrong?

Comment: @smartmouse no there is no way you can edit this question to make it a programming question because it has nothing to do with programming, it is about you wanting to know how many times people have downloaded your app

Comment: What could i do now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to code for that if you want exact number of download.
create a webservice as the app starts by sending serial number of device to server.
keep the record over there.